# Problem of running services in background after API 23 in Android App

Tags: android

I am developing a Android App. Problem is - How to run services in background permanently even after removing the app from recent task in above API 23?? Like notification service of Whatsapp always running in background.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the article to create never ending background service [NaverEndingBAckgroundService](https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-)

android

Comment: Error 404. Thanks ! It might be helpful.